# How to modify a 3d array using numpy block without for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to modify block elements of 3d array without for loop. Without loop because it is the bottleneck of my code.

To illustrate what I want, I draw a figure:

[image]

The code with for loop:

```py
import numpy as np

# Create 3d array with 2x4x4 elements
a = np.arange(2*4*4).reshape(2,4,4)
b = np.zeros(np.shape(a))

# Change Block Elements

for it1 in range(2):
    b[it1]= np.block([[a[it1,0:2,0:2], a[it1,2:4,0:2]],[a[it1,0:2,2:4], a[it1,2:4,2:4]]] )
```

Comment: My actual code is more sophisticated one. In addition to change red and green blocks, I take complex conjugates of red and only transpose of green, so it is not simply transposing 3d array

Comment: If you want to handle a more sophisticated case, you should make that clear in your question, although the complex conjugate can only be done with normal slicing

Comment: Also, which corner is 0,0 in your picture? Lower left?

Comment: I found you a faster way. Also, don't forget to upvote the folks that helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's see if there's a way to do what you want for a 2D array using only indexing, `reshape`, and `transpose` operations. If there is, then there's a good chance that you can extend it to a larger number of dimensions.

```
x = np.arange(2 * 3 * 2 * 5).reshape(2 * 3, 2 * 5)
```

Clearly you can reshape this into an array that has the blocks along a separate dimension:

```
x.reshape(2, 3, 2, 5)
```

Then you can transpose the resulting blocks:

```
x.reshape(2, 3, 2, 5).transpose(2, 1, 0, 3)
```

So far, none of the data has been copied. To make the copy happen, reshape back into the original shape:

```
x.reshape(2, 3, 2, 5).transpose(2, 1, 0, 3).reshape(2 * 3, 2 * 5)
```

Adding additional leading dimensions is as simple as increasing the number of the dimensions you want to swap:

```
b = a.reshape(a.shape[0], 2, a.shape[1] // 2, 2, a.shape[2] // 2).transpose(0, 3, 2, 1, 4).reshape(a.shape)
```

Here is a quick benchmark of the other implementations with your original array:

```
a = np.arange(2*4*4).reshape(2,4,4)

%%timeit
b = np.zeros(np.shape(a))
for it1 in range(2):
    b[it1] = np.block([[a[it1, 0:2, 0:2], a[it1, 2:4, 0:2]], [a[it1, 0:2, 2:4], a[it1, 2:4, 2:4]]])
    
27.7 µs ± 107 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%%timeit
b = a.copy()
b[:,0:2,2:4], b[:,2:4,0:2] = b[:,2:4,0:2].copy(), b[:,0:2,2:4].copy()

2.22 µs ± 3.89 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit b = np.block([[a[:,0:2,0:2], a[:,2:4,0:2]],[a[:,0:2,2:4], a[:,2:4,2:4]]])

13.6 µs ± 217 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit b = a.reshape(a.shape[0], 2, a.shape[1] // 2, 2, a.shape[2] // 2).transpose(0, 3, 2, 1, 4).reshape(a.shape)

1.27 µs ± 14.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

For small arrays, the differences can sometimes be attributed to overhead. Here is a more meaningful comparison with arrays of size 10x1000x1000, split into 10 500x500 blocks:

```
a = np.arange(10*1000*1000).reshape(10, 1000, 1000)

%%timeit
b = np.zeros(np.shape(a))
for it1 in range(10):
    b[it1]= np.block([[a[it1,0:500,0:500], a[it1,500:1000,0:500]],[a[it1,0:500,500:1000], a[it1,500:1000,500:1000]]])

58 ms ± 904 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
b = a.copy()
b[:,0:500,500:1000], b[:,500:1000,0:500] = b[:,500:1000,0:500].copy(), b[:,0:500,500:1000].copy()

41.2 ms ± 688 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit b = np.block([[a[:,0:500,0:500], a[:,500:1000,0:500]],[a[:,0:500,500:1000], a[:,500:1000,500:1000]]])

27.5 ms ± 569 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit b = a.reshape(a.shape[0], 2, a.shape[1] // 2, 2, a.shape[2] // 2).transpose(0, 3, 2, 1, 4).reshape(a.shape)

20 ms ± 161 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So it seems that using numpy's own reshaping and transposition mechanism is fastest on my computer. Also, notice that the overhead of `np.block` becomes less important than copying the temporary arrays as size gets bigger, so the other two implementations change places.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly replace the `it1` by a slice of the whole dimension:

```
b = np.block([[a[:,0:2,0:2], a[:,2:4,0:2]],[a[:,0:2,2:4], a[:,2:4,2:4]]])
```

Comment: Your answer is faster than @Alex's for larger arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Will it make it faster?

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(2*4*4).reshape(2,4,4)
b = a.copy()
b[:,0:2,2:4], b[:,2:4,0:2] = b[:,2:4,0:2].copy(), b[:,0:2,2:4].copy()
```

Comparison with np.block() alternative from another answer.
**Option 1**:

```
%timeit b = a.copy(); b[:,0:2,2:4], b[:,2:4,0:2] = b[:,2:4,0:2].copy(), b[:,0:2,2:4].copy()
```

Output:

```
5.44 µs ± 134 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

**Option 2**

```py
%timeit b = np.block([[a[:,0:2,0:2], a[:,2:4,0:2]],[a[:,0:2,2:4], a[:,2:4,2:4]]])
```

Output:

```
30.6 µs ± 1.75 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Comment: Quite elegant, you can save some more resources by removing the first `copy` in that line:  `d[:,0:2,2:4], d[:,2:4,0:2] = d[:,2:4,0:2], d[:,0:2,2:4].copy()`

Comment: maybe, but on such a small array, %timeit doesn't show a noticeable improvement in speed. But can be tested with larger arrays. The potential more perplexity of the array in memory as a result may let know of itself down the road though.

Comment: I found an even faster way :) I like the benchmarks.